# What type of coating is on my basement slab?

Tags: flooring

1984 construction has a basement that was intended as semi finished but prior owner took no care of it. What is this flooring? My first thought is just concrete with epoxy that’s well worn. But the stains on the green hallway section hint that maybe there was another product on there before.

I am hoping to add a living space down here. What can I do with this flooring?

(Don’t worry about water damage spots, those are just stains from something that’s been addressed.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you get us closer than 5 feet away? What problem are you trying to solve? You can put about anything over that without issue. I'd probably lay vinyl plank.

Comment: VtC as most of the answers are primarily addressing the "what can I do with it" part and the answer to that is "pretty much anything", as particularly highlighted in [Ecnerwal's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/287969/34147).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be paint or epoxy. Hard to tell without looking at it directly.

As to the beige stuff, it looks like a cheap carpet job. The top photo shows something with a narrow notch in it, so it's probably carpet glue. It's a "cheap" job, because normally you glue the whole area, not just the edges.

> I am hoping to add a living space down here. What can I do with this flooring?

Put a floating floor over it. You'll need

1. A plastic barrier of some sort
2. Padding
3. Your flooring material. I highly recommend 5 mil (or greater) vinyl
4. Quarter round (pre-primed if possible) and some white paint

The advantage of this is it doesn't matter what's on the floor now. If it's level, a floating floor means you just go over the top of it all and call it good. Very much a DIY project.

Answer (score 1):

"What can I do with this flooring?"

The answer depends greatly on what you desire to have as the finished floor?

As it is now you have no "flooring", you have a slab that has paint on some sections and  glue residue on the edges of other other places.

What you need to do can range from; nothing at all, to some scraping and/or grinding to remove the glue residue.

"What type of coating is on my basement slab?"  The answers are moot.

There is no way to answer what you can or need to do unless you provide us with  what finish flooring you wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

What can you do with it:

1. Fresh coat of paint.
2. Thinset & tile
3. New glue and carpet (or carpet tiles) (until the next water problem)
4. Take a terrazzo grinder to it
5. Barrier and ill-fated hardwood (tilting at windmills in a basement)
6. Barrier and plastic fake wood, or plastic fake something else
7. Rubber mats (foam or solid)
8. Cork
9. ...

I'd say 2 is your best option, because today's fixed water problem is unlikely to be the last, historically. Basements are difficult that way. You can use the fake wood tiles for a wood look, or you can embrace tile and use some part of the thousands of years of decorative tiling approaches to make an interesting and beautiful floor.